# How to store form data and local storage data to database

Tags: typescript, angular7

I want to store my form data and data from local storage at the same time.

```
 Save(add: NgForm)
 {

  let formvalue=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('datasource'));
  let data=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));
     this.addservice.add(data).subscribe(res=>{
       if(res){
        this.addservice.add(formvalue);
       }})

   this.objadd=new Data();
   this.objadd.description=formadd.value.name;
   this.addservice.add(this.objadd).subscribe(res=>{
     if(res){
   // this.addservice.add(this.formadd.value)
   }});    
  this.addservice.add(formvalue + this.formadd.value);
 }
```

here it is my second component's save method I m saving data from local storage which works completely fine but how to store second component's form data and local storage data at the same time into the database it executes two times and I m getting two entries into a database.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array and push new values to the array.

```
The sequence would be something like:


      Save(add: NgForm)
     {

      let formvalue,data: {
    "name": string;
    "countryID": string;
}
     formvalue={ "name":"Abc", "countryID":"1" };
     data={ "name":"Abc", "countryID":"1" };
     var array = JSON.parse('[]');

        array.push(data);
        localStorage.setItem('Data', JSON.stringify(array));


     this.addservice.add(array).subscribe(res=>{
       if(res){
        console.log("Res- >" +res);
       }})
     }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195809/discussion-on-answer-by-orbit-how-to-store-form-data-and-local-storage-data-to-d). Please be sure to [edit] the answer to include all relevant information from chat.